# ios coverflow displaying many items like three instead of one at a time

Tags: ios, coverflow

I want to implementing coverflow like the one on the below image show below (instead of showing 1 at a time it can show many like 3 at a time). Can someone help me on the approach, or lead me to any tutorial will be appreciated[image]
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i understood from your question is that you want to implement coverflow.

so u can achieve this using by adding UIScrollView to UItableView Cell, if you want only one row then just play with our few tableView delegate methods.

[This tutorial help you to proceed. revert back if you need any help.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

**EDIT:**

also take a look at this post: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324514/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-a-uitableviewcell)