# UIScrollView with UIPageControl in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create something like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no).

Here is the sample code which I tried:

> -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
>   {
>       static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RefundMeCell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

UIImageView *rowImageView=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *questionOptionLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UIImageView *collapseImageView=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
UIScrollView *scrollView=(UIScrollView*)[cell viewWithTag:4];
UIImageView *sampleImageView=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:5];
UIButton *sampleButton=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:6];
UILabel *instructionHeaderLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:7];
UILabel *instructionsLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:8];
UIPageControl *pgCntrl=(UIPageControl*)[cell viewWithTag:9];

[rowImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalcell.png"]];
questionOptionLabel.text = @"";
collapseImageView.image = nil;
scrollView.hidden = YES;
sampleImageView.image = nil;sampleImageView.hidden = YES;
sampleButton.hidden = YES;
instructionHeaderLabel.text = @"";instructionHeaderLabel.hidden = YES;
instructionsLabel.text = @"";instructionsLabel.hidden = YES;
pgCntrl.hidden = YES;


[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userImageButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


sampleImageView.image = nil;

[collapseImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"]];
questionOptionLabel.text=@"";
instructionHeaderLabel.text=@"Instructions";

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    instructionHeaderLabel.hidden = NO;
    sampleImageView.image = self.barcodeImage;
    scrollView.hidden = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    pgCntrl.hidden = NO;
    sampleImageView.hidden = NO;
    sampleButton.hidden = NO;
    pgCntrl.numberOfPages = 5;
    pgCntrl.currentPage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        [scrollView addSubview:sampleImageView];
        [scrollView addSubview:sampleButton];
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 5, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
else
{
    instructionHeaderLabel.hidden = NO;
    sampleImageView.image = nil;
    scrollView.hidden = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    pgCntrl.hidden = NO;
    sampleImageView.hidden = NO;
    sampleButton.hidden = NO;
    pgCntrl.numberOfPages = 3;
    pgCntrl.currentPage = 0;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

return cell;
```

> }

My problem is, how I can add `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, etc when `UIScrollView` is scrolled to second page?

It should look like this

[image]

Currently `UIImageView`, `UILabel` is shown only first time. when I scroll to second page, `UIImageView` and `UILabel` scroll back and nothing is shown on second page.

Comment: Why do you need to add images when you scroll? Can you just add it right away and scroll will just reveal them?

Comment: @ image, you can upload an image to websites like tinypic and share the link to it.

@ second page, do you want to lazy-load the data? If that is what you want, you might find some open-source libraries for that. :)

Comment: @OlegFedorov I need to take product images from different dimensions(top,bottom,etc) and label provides instructions.

Comment: @Sufian this is the tinyurl link [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=97snib&s=8)

Comment: @Maverick, you can add this link to your question.
http://oi60.tinypic.com/97snib.jpg

Comment: @Maverick so you want each page to have an image and a label?

Comment: @jafar yes u are correct, each image and label text would be different and this will depend on the data that I receive from server.

Comment: @Maverick if jafar has answered your question, accept the answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a different approach because your solution is not scalable. If you want n pages you'll have to add n images & label to your scroll view which will be a mess and also not memory efficient.

Give a look at [this library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/swipeview) I think it will suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  tableObj.dataSource = self;
  tableObj.delegate = self;
  scrollView.delegate = self;
    // customObj = [[customCellForText alloc]init];
   imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"man-actor-Ashton-Kutcher-Wallpaper.jpg"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Man-Booker-Prize-judges-p-011.jpg"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"man-curl.jpg"]
  ,nil];

    // pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 180, 100, 30)];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
  customCellForText *cell = [tableObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCellForText" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 80, 150, 100)];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    //[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++){
      CGRect frame;
      frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

      subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      subview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
      subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

    }

  pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]init];
  pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(170, 180, 100, 30);
  pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
  pageControl.currentPage = 0;
  pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = YES;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:pageControl];
  [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  cell.nameLabel.text=@"amol";

  return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{

    CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
     int newPage = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

  self.pageControl.currentPage = newPage;

  }
```