# UIScrollView within a custom UITableViewCell not working ios7.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I implemented a horizontal UIScrollView inside a custom UITableViewCell. It works fine when built on ios 8.1 simulator/device. But the content doesn't scroll in ios 7.1 simulator. I had googled about this for a while. Unfortunately nothing helps.

My situation is just like this one. : [Horizontal UIScrollView inside custom UITableViewCell - using IB Storyboard - Not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no)

But the given solution doesn't work with mine..

I have  a subclassed UITableViewCell CTCurrentListingCell

```
@interface CTCurrentListingsCell ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end


@implementation CTCurrentListingsCell

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];
 [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 [_scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
 [_scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
 [_scrollView setDelegate:self];
 [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(520, 91)];
}

-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity   targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
 NSLog(@" scroll offset %@ ",NSStringFromCGPoint( scrollView.contentOffset));
 if(targetContentOffset->x!=320)
   {
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 91) animated:YES];

   }

}
@end
```

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue ?

Comment: yes. I created a new view for cell in a xib file.

Comment: also there was a pan gesture recognizer inside the viewcontroller. So i had to make it not respond inside the cell