# How to add XYPieChart and PNBarChart in same prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My requirement is simple. I want to load a pie chart in first index of a UITableView. When I swipe right, pie chart (XYPieChart) should be replaced with a bar chart (PNBarChart). I have separately loaded pie chart and bar chart in separate rows. How can I achieve that swipe effect in UITableview.?

A UIView has to be added into the prototype cell and custom class of UIView has to set to XYPieChart and PNBarChart in the Identity Inspector in Xcode.

What I expect is an effect like page controller, but page controller loads two view controllers. Right?

Can I add a Page Control inside a prototype cell and add two UIViews into the page control?
Will the views change when I swipe the row?
I'm attaching some screenshots with this for clarity.

[Pie Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXQi.jpg)

[Pie Chart and Bar Chart in two rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4V2e.png)

Comment: I thinks you are asking something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no

Comment: You can add page control in your table view cell

Comment: @shuvo : But using a scrollview will only allow me to scroll the table row. Right?
What I want is a swipe effect. Just like page controller.

Comment: @BhupatBheda : Can I add UIViews instead of view controllers into page control inside tableviewcell

Comment: Do one thing take UIview inside UIview add scrollview and pagecontrol

Comment: @roshith.balendran i make one demo for you let me share with you

Comment: Please have a look i did in table view cell if its Ok then let me know http://makeagif.com/gif/-Y_Yfjx

Comment: @BhupatBheda : I checked the gif, that is exactly what I want.
I have configured the pie chart and bar chart in the awakenib method of corresponding UITableViewCell.m...
I hope, when I swipe the cell can I reload the view.
Do you think both charts will work in this method of yours?
Can you share me any sample code.?

Comment: @roshith.balendran i did in code in swift can you convert into Objective-c

Comment: @BhupatBheda : I will try. Please post the link...

Comment: @roshith.balendran i put my answer please check and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: @BhupatBheda : I will check and let you know. Thanks anyway for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this But code is in Swift

First Create Tableviewcontroller from Storyboard

[image]

Create CustomCell of TableView

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControll: UIPageControl!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**Now In Tableviewcontroller and add delegate UIScrollViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource**

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomCell;

    let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = tableView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = cell.contentView.frame.height
    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
    imgOne.tag = 1
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth, y:0,width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
    imgTwo.tag = 1
    cell.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    cell.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)

    cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:scrollViewWidth * 2, height:cell.scrollView.frame.height)
    cell.scrollView.delegate = self
    cell.pageControll.currentPage = 0
    pageCtrl = cell.pageControll
    return cell;
}
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    if (scrollView.superview?.superview as? CustomCell) != nil{

        let cell = scrollView.superview?.superview as! CustomCell
        let pageWidth:CGFloat = self.view.frame.width

        let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1

        cell.pageControll.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
    }

}
```